# Context menu is opening when it shouln't (if...elif)

Tags: python, pyqt, contextmenu, pyqt5

I have a QTableWidget with 8 columns, and I want the context menu to open only in the first one (column 0) since in the rest of the columns I use the right click for a different action.

When I first start the program everything works as it should: If I right click first in a cell of the column 3 for example it does what it should (substract 1 from the cell value) and it doesn't open the context menu, perfect.

BUT after I do right click on the column 0 first to open the context menu (it works fine), if I go back to column 3 and right click... The context menu opens! And it also does the action it should (substracting one from the cell value)!

Here is the code I'm using:

```
class Table(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
            cellExited = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)
            itemExited = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
            self.setItemDelegate(ReadOnlyDelegate(self))
            self._last_index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex()
            self.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
            self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)

            self.popMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
            self.popMenu.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('Action 1', self))
            self.popMenu.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('Action 2', self))
            self.popMenu.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('Action 3', self))

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        it = self.itemAt(event.pos())
        print(it.column())    #DEBUG
        if it.column()>0:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                it.setText(str(round(float(it.text()) + 1,2)))
            elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
                it.setText(str(round(float(it.text()) - 1,2)))
        elif it.column() == 0 and event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print(it.column() == 0)    #DEBUG
            print(event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton)    #DEBUG        
            self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu)

    def on_context_menu(self, point):
        self.popMenu.exec_(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(point))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting an event handler (`on_context_menu`) to an event (`customContextMenuRequested`) in another event handler (`mousePressEvent`) seems unorthodox.

Instead you can connect the events in the `__init__` method.  This means moving `self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu)` into `__init__`.
Then in `on_context_menu` you should check for which the context menu was requested and only show it if it is the first column:

```
def on_context_menu(self, point):
    # the ... should be replaced by code that gets the column on which the event occurred
    column == ...
    if column == 0:
        self.popMenu.exec_(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(point))
```

(I don't actually know how to get the column inside `on_context_menu`)

Then inside `mousePressEvent` you don't need the whole `elif` part any more.

Comment: This works for me! For the column number I did create a global variable that equals 1 and it only turns to 0 if the elif meets the conditions. Then after calling on_context_menu and showing the menu it resets the column number to 1 again so the column condition of the elif isnt met if we right-click in a different column after it. Thanks!

Comment: @LeonBrasero Glad to help.  Please do not forget to accept an answer if you think it solves your problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

`self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_context_menu)` means you're connecting an event `customContextMenuRequested` to the method `self.on_context_menu`. Every time the event happens (every time there's a right click probably), the method will be called.

The first time you right click on column 0, you connect the event to the method. Every right click from then on will call the method.

What you want is to called `self.on_context_menu` directly, as in:

```
def mousePressEvent(...):
   ....
   elif it.column() == 0 ... :
        self.on_context_menu()
```

Comment: Hi Mel, thanks for your help but I'm afraid that if I try this the context menu wont open, even on the first column. I also edited the OP to include the `__init__` method, where I declare the popMenu widget.